# Invertir una lista mediante .reverse() en una línea

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un Kata en Codewars para practicar, y me encuentro con que no funciona como yo esperaba. En un boceto de parte de la solución, me encuentro con que este fragmento no produce el resultado que espero:

```
def digitize(n):
  l = list(str(n)).reverse()
  print(l) 

digitize(12345)
>>> None
```

Sin embargo:

```
def digitize(n):
  l = list(str(n))
  l.reverse()
  print(l) 

digitize(12345)
>>> ["5", "4", "3", "2", "1"]
```

Me ayudaría bastante entender porqué se comporta de esa manera

Comment: si utilizo `return(l)` el resultado es `>>> [ ]`

Comment: Haciendo la prueba el resultado es el mismo, None

Comment: `reverse` no retorna nada, o sea, retorna `None`. Estas asignando el resultado de `reverse` a `l`.

Answer (score 4):

Toda función eventualmente puede tener: (1) un valor de retorno (2) un efecto colateral. En este caso `reverse()` solo tiene el efecto colateral que es el de invertir el orden de una lista "in place", sin retornar ningún valor.  De ahi que cuando haces esto:

```
l = list(str(n)).reverse()
```

`l` vale `None`por que es lo que en definitiva retorna el `reverse()`. Lo adecuado  sería hacer:

```
l = list(str(n))
l.reverse()
print(l)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me has resuelto la duda perfectamente

Comment: Para que la gente entienda por qué no he entendido nada hasta este comentario, imaginaos que vais a aprender JavaScript y os dicen que `.toString()` sobreescribe el objeto y devuelve `undefined`. 
Cuando lo que hace `toString()` es retornar un string.

Answer (score 1):

## Teoría

Las listas son objetos *mutables*, lo que quiere decir que puedes alterar lo que contienen. Cuando pasas una lista a una función, la función puede por tanto alterar los contenidos de la lista que recibió como parámetro. Por ejemplo, la siguiente función pone a cero todos los elementos de la lista que reciba:

```
def ceros(lista):
   for i in range(len(lista)):
       lista[i] = 0
```

Si llamas a esta función así:

```
ejemplo = [1, 2, 3]
ceros(ejemplo)
```

encontrarás que a la vuelta `ejemplo` contiene `[0, 0, 0]`. Si en cambio hubieras hecho:

```
ejemplo = [1, 2, 3]
ejemplo = ceros(ejemplo)
```

entonces estarías sobreescribiendo la variable `ejemplo` (que había sido modificada por la función), y asignándole un nuevo valor: el que retorne la función. Ya que esta función no tiene ningún `return` explícito, retorna `None`, por lo que al final de ese código `ejemplo` valdrá `None`. Ya no será una lista. La lista `[0,0,0]` que la función había construido se pierde y el recolector de basura de Python la borrará.

Todo lo anterior es un ejemplo de una función con *efectos colaterales*, y por tanto *impura*. Se denomina función pura a la que no tiene ningún efecto colateral (no altera ninguna variable del programa que la llamó).

Una versión pura de la función sería esta:

```
def ceros(lista):
    return [0]*len(lista)
```

En este caso no se modifica en absoluto la lista que recibe como parámetro, sino que en cambio retorna una *nueva lista* que tiene tantos ceros como elementos tenía la original.

Si ahora la invocas así:

```
ejemplo = [1, 2, 3]
ejemplo = ceros(ejemplo)
```

la varible `ejemplo` tendrá al final `[0,0,0]`, pero no porque la función la haya modificado, sino porque el programa que llamó a la función ha decidido descartar la lista original y reasignar el identificador `ejemplo` para que apunte a la nueva lista resultante. Pero igualmente podrías haber escrito:

```
ejemplo = [1, 2, 3]
otra = ceros(ejemplo)
```

que deja más claro que la lista original `ejemplo` no se ha tocado, sino que se ha creado `otra`.

## Reverse y sort

Los métodos `list.reverse()` y `list.sort()` operan directamente sobre la lista en cuestión. No es que sean exactamente funciones impuras, pues en este caso son métodos del objeto `list`, pero debes tener presente que alteran directamente el objeto sobre el que actúan, y retornan `None`.

Te interesará saber que existe versión *funcional pura* de estas operaciones, y es a través de `reversed()` y `sorted()`.

`reversed(lista)` genera una nueva lista (sin alterar a la original). En realidad lo que devuelve es un iterador, pero éste puede ser convertido a lista. Utilizando esto en tu código se escribiría así:

```py
def digitize(n):
  l = list(reversed(str(n)))
  print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Los métodos de las listas realizan acciones IN-PLACE, esto es, en la misma lista y no retornan una lista nueva con los resultados. Al no retornar una nueva lista, la funcion `print` imprime `None` porque no tiene nada que imprimir.

Por ejemplo:

```
lista = [5, 1, 2, 4, 6]
print(sort(list))
```

Esto imprimirá la lista ordenada porque la funcion `sort` retorna una lista ordenada a partir de una lista desordenada.

Por otro lado:

```
print(lista.sorted())
print(lista)
```

Imprimirá `None` porque el método `sorted` de la lista ordena la lista misma y a diferencia de `sort` no retorna nada... pero a continuación imprimirá la lista ordenada ya que se esta imprimiendo el estado actual de la lista.